# Fancybox popup is to small

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

On [this website](http://www.podiumverhuurhaaglanden.nl/NL/prijslijst/licht-geluid) I have a link that should result in a popup with text and an image, but the popup is too small.

The size of the picture is different for each link. 
How can I chnage the popup script so that the picture would fit and there is no scrollbar vissible?

The php script I use is this:

```
<a class="text fancybox.iframe"  href="/'.$lang.'/producten/'.$producten['code'].'" class="inline" title="'.$producten['naam'].'">
```

And this is the part of the script where I call the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    $(".text").fancybox({
     autoSize    : true
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, it did the trick for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").fancybox({
     fitToView  : false,
    autoSize    : false,
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this first http://fancybox.net/blog  or

fixing code (for your scale)

```
$(".text").fancybox({  
       width    : 500px ,  
       height   : 500px 
})
```

or

```
'scrolling'     : 'no',
```

Comment: width and height can change to you size :)

Comment: The problem is that every picture has another size. I did find the scrolling : no feature. But then only the scrollbar is gone and a big part of the picture can not beenn seen.

Comment: i think set min-width and min-height or max-width and max-height can help this @Coolen